# send push notification using firebase among multiple android devices

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have seen that most of the android tutorial are sending a push notificaiton using an website system to control how to send to the devices. Is there a method to send from an android device to another android device and the device can automatically compose the message to the other devices without extra setting?? Thank you.

Comment: Sending a message *to* a device requires a request to FCM that specifies the **server key**. As its name implies this key should only be used in a trusted process on a server.

Answer (score 0):

Sure create a custom server, send the token and message to server, the token must identify the user device that will compose the message. When the message is received on the composer end, send another token and message to the server, this time along with a field(composer) thus identifying and agreeing that this token will compose a message. use appropriate mechanisms to handle such a request. Make sense? so basically it's just sending multiple but from different and each device creates special field identifying the intent of the message.

Comment: So this means that I need to set up an external server? May I juat use firebase abd devices to do that?

Comment: no this functionality is very custom, you could fire-base standard messaging but it is less flexible and manageable. make sense?

Comment: does this answer not suit your requirements?